# bash script: passing arguments to mkfs

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I'm writing a bash script to format my partitions. One of the commands I want to run is the following:

```
mkfs.btrfs -f -m single -L root /dev/sda1
```

So I have split that command into the options part: `-f -m single -L root` 
and the partition part: `/dev/sda1`
and put them into variables like this:

```
mkfs.btrfs "${myoptions}" /dev/"${mypartition}"
```

but it fails with:

```
mkfs.btrfs: invalid option -- ´ ´
```

I have tried different variations of it like putting the 2 parts in doubles quotes but all fails. I have also tried to put the two parts into an array and run it like this:

```
mkfs.btrfs "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}"
```

or like this:

```
mkfs.btrfs "${array[*]}"
```

but it also fails.

If I run it without the options part it works, so my guess is that the issue comes from the empty space between the two arguments but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you specify how you have run the script on CLI ? It might just be that you have to put your arguments in quotes. Like : $ script "-f -m single -L root" "sda1"

Comment: It's apparently the spaces (all of them) like @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have also tried to put the two parts into an array...

Not good enough. **Every single argument** must be an element of an array (or the only value in the variable).

```
args1=(-f -m single -L root)
args2=/dev/"$mypartition"
mkfs.btrfs "${args1[@]}" "$args2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is always a huge pain for me. In this case since none of your arguments have spaces themselves, I would try removing the double quotes and letting Bash break it into words for your `$myoptions` variable. So this:

`mkfs.btrfs ${myoptions} /dev/"${mypartition}"`

With the double quotes you get one field, `-f -m single -L root` containing spaces. Without it, it should be broken into the individual fields `-f` `-m` `single` `-L` and `root` and show the same behavior as typing `mkfs.btrfs -f -m single -L root /dev/sda1` in the interactive shell.

If you do have some arguments that contain spaces, you might have to get tricky with the `$IFS` variable and your encoding.

You can also use the special variable `$@` which has its own rules.

I write all my shell stuff to POSIX though so I'm sure there's an easier way to do this in Bash.

Comment: I tried this: mkfs.btrfs ${myoptions} /dev/"${mypartition}" again but it didn't work. I took a look at this special variable $@ but if I'm not wrong it's for functions you define yourself and not given functions.

Comment: No you're right, I thought removing the quotes would work in this specific case and be simple. `$@` is a special parameter you can mimic the behavior of an array with because `sh` doesn't have an array. Honestly, I write my scripts to be `sh` compatible because I enjoy it and it's supported in all POSIX compatible shells, including Bash. If you're interested just for fun, http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html is a short, well written and presented list of some of the more useful tricks (including using `$@`).